# babel-node Error: Cannot find module '../es'

Tags: node.js, npm, babeljs, babel-node, core-js

When I run my app, I keep running into the below `MODULE_NOT_FOUND` error.

I have cleaned Docker, `yarn clean`, restarted my computer, delete the repo and cloned an entirely new repo, and this error keeps happening. My colleagues do not run into this error, either. Does anyone have any ideas?

My `.babelrc` file:

```
{
  "presets": [
    [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      {
        "targets": {
          "node": true
        }
      }
    ]
  ],
  "plugins": [
  "@babel/plugin-transform-arrow-functions",
  "@babel/plugin-syntax-object-rest-spread",
  ]
}
```

Error:

```
om_cart        | internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:960
om_cart        |   throw err;
om_cart        |   ^
om_cart        |
om_cart        | Error: Cannot find module '../es'
om_cart        | Require stack:
om_cart        | - /app/node_modules/@babel/node/node_modules/core-js/stable/index.js
om_cart        | - /app/node_modules/@babel/node/lib/_babel-node.js
om_cart        |     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:957:15)
om_cart        |     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:840:27)
om_cart        |     at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1019:19)
om_cart        |     at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:77:18)
om_cart        |     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/@babel/node/node_modules/core-js/stable/index.js:1:1)
om_cart        |     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1133:30)
om_cart        |     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1153:10)
om_cart        |     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:977:32)
om_cart        |     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:877:14)
om_cart        |     at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1019:19) {
om_cart        |   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
om_cart        |   requireStack: [
om_cart        |     '/app/node_modules/@babel/node/node_modules/core-js/stable/index.js',
om_cart        |     '/app/node_modules/@babel/node/lib/_babel-node.js'
om_cart        |   ]
om_cart        | }
om_cart        | [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Answer (score 1):

Just fixed the problem.

I deleted the `node_modules` and `package-lock.json` files.

Then ran `npm install` and `yarn dev` it worked.

Comment: As suggestion I would use `yarn` or `npm`, they are supposed to be alternatives for the same tasks. They also create different lock files. So instead of running `npm install` just run `yarn install`. Or something like `npm install` and `npm run dev`